# Ski road trip from San Francisco to New York

Tags: usa, car-rentals, road-trips, skiing

I'm planning a road trip starting out in SF and heading across country via a few ski resorts ending up in Binghamton area, New York.

The route so far looks like:

SF --> South Lake Tahoe (ski Heavenly)

Tahoe --> Salt Lake City (ski Solitude)

Salt Lake --> Vail, CO (ski Vail)

Vail --> Chicago (no skiing)

Chicago --> Binghamton

I'm looking for suggestions of possible places to ski between Vail and Binghamton which don't take us off the route too much?  We're only planning on taking a maximum of 2 and a half weeks on this trip with one or two days skiing per resort.

Also, if anyone has any suggestions on a good car rental place for this I'd be most grateful, so far prices are coming up in the $1400 range.

Comment: Is the stop in Chicago mandatory? Taking the straight shot on Interstate 80 takes you past a few ski areas in Iowa, then some areas east of Cleveland. Routing on Interstates 70 and 64, however, puts you in range of many more options in Missouri, southern Indiana, Kentucky, and West Virginia, while adding just a few hours total to the trip if Google Maps is reliable. And the Ozarks and Appalachians are probably more credible mountains.

Comment: We could certainly remove the Chicago stop for more skiing! I'll check out skiing along 70 and 64 too, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you hit Chicago, would you consider packing your passport and swinging through Ontario en route to NY?  Blue Mountain is an option, then head down to Binghamton, adding maybe 5 hrs to the overall drive.  If drive time is not a huge concern, you could take it a step further and hit both Blue Mt as well as Lake Placid on the way to Binghamton (granted you'd have to go a little more east than originally planned).  Blue Mt vertical descent is only about 700 ft, so not going to be like Solitude, Heavenly or Vail.  Lake Placid is  4x that.

Comment: You know, I'd not thought about heading up that way and it looks like a good possibility too, thanks for the suggestion!